# no overload for method 'Open'/'Run' takes '1' arguments

Tags: c#, macros

I met this problem as title showed when I editing script task in C # in SSIS, I tried several solutions found online, but don't work. can you find out why?

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;using System;
using System.IO;using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace ST_46fccdfebfc844059ab81e95c062c19e.csproj
{
[System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

    public void Main()
    {

        string File_name = "c:\\Documents and Settings\\richard.gui\\Desktop\\ARupload.xlsm";
        string Macro_name = "test";

        Excel.Application ExcelObject = default(Excel.Application);

        Excel.Workbooks oBooks = default(Excel.Workbooks);
        Excel.WorkbookClass oBook = default(Excel.WorkbookClass);

        ExcelObject.Visible = true;

        oBooks = ExcelObject.Workbooks;
        oBook = (Excel.WorkbookClass)oBooks.Open(File_name);

        ExcelObject.Run(Macro_name);

        oBook.Save();
        ExcelObject.Application.Quit();
        ExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = true;

        ExcelObject = null;
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168292(v=office.11).aspx

Perhaps try something like this:

```
// C#
Excel.Workbook wb = ThisApplication.Workbooks.Open( 
"C:\\YourPath\\Yourworkbook.xls", 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: good points, it solved the problem of open (), while when using the same way in 'ExcelObject.Run(Macro_name)', the second error is still there.

Comment: You need to Add the same parameters for Run() looks like 30 parameters but it depends on the version you are using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx

Comment: Hi Jras, it does need  macro + 30 parameters, while i am still testing   with different words similar to 'Type.Missing','arg1' to fill up the parameters. no success at the moment.

Comment: Hi Jras, I rewrote 30 times Type.Missing to replace the parameters'place, all errors have been solved. However, the macro in excel did not run successfully, instead of that, the visual studio 2008 opened a new page.

Comment: update:Type.Missing can be used for run(), but be careful with the format need to be 30 times.