# Get total number of used rows in Excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I was trying to count the used rows in excel. The following is my code. I got error when passing the filename to the Open() function. The error message is No overload for method 'Open' take '1' argument.
I really appreciate any kinds of help. Thanks!

```
 public static int GetTableRows(string fileName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


        var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@fileName);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;


        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        return rowCount;


    }
```

Comment: Do you mind specifying what exactly the *error* you get?

Comment: yes. It is No overload for method 'Open' take '1' argument

Comment: What version of `Office.Interop` are you using? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292182/4934172).

Comment: One more thing, the `@` before the `filenName` variable isn't required. It's only required when you type a string literal (a non-escaped string between double quotes).

Comment: Is your excel file in a static location?

Comment: This should work. Otherwise look at the signature of the `Open` method and provide other non-optional parameters.

Comment: Nope. they are dynamic.

Comment: Okay. I will check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code which you write
int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;

it will only calculate the Number of Columns.

if you want to calculate the number of rows then you have to write this one code
xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).